# Get all data within date range (day and month) based on input date

Tags: sql, oracle, select, where-clause

I have a question regarding the following SQL. I have an input date parameter, let's say 15.02.2021. Moreover, I have a table with n-objects and they all have a birthdate x, e.g.

| Client ID | Birthdate |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 15.01.1950 |
| 2 | 27.03.1976 |
| 3 | 29.03.1980 |
| 4 | 15.04.2000 |
| 5 | 07.05.1989 |

Birthday is of data type "date".

I have to retrieve the data based on the following criteria: I always check data at the 15th of every month (this date being my input date parameter) and I need to get all customers with their birthday in 2 1/2 months from now. Meaning: Checking which customers are affected on 15.02.2021 should lead to all clients having their birthday within 01.04 until 30.04 --> customer with client id 4

How is the where clause written in this case?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Column Birthdate data type?

Comment: @jarlh: Data Type: Date

Comment: DB used - Oracle (tag added to question @Gordon Linoff)

Answer (score 1):

You appear to want to just compare the month of the date to the month of the current day plus 2.5 months. For that, you can use:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  EXTRACT( MONTH FROM birthdate ) = EXTRACT( MONTH FROM ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, 2.5) )
```

It may be that you don't need to add the half-month (since you are using it in the middle of the month and expecting that adding half a month will take it to the last day of the month rather than the next month) and can simplify it to:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  EXTRACT( MONTH FROM birthdate ) = EXTRACT( MONTH FROM ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, 2) )
```

If you want to replace the current date with a fixed value then you can replace `SYSDATE` with, for example, `DATE '2020-02-15'`.

Comment: . . Now I understand your answer.